# Show config file content C#

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

I have a C# windows application.
With in a application I want to show my config file content in a text box.
I can read the config file.But I don't know how to show that in a text box.
How can I do this?

Comment: What format is the config file?

Comment: format mean? that is in visual studio App.config

Comment: Read the file in a string builder and then put that in the text box.

Comment: oh I see, it's your App.Config, do you want to pull out any particular settings?

Comment: `TextBox1.Text = str` thats the format to assign string `str` to a textbox

Comment: Whole config file content I want to show as it is..

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?:

```
textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
```

Comment: yours has more detail, so deleting mine :)

Comment: Yes ..That's what I wanted.. Thanks David

Comment: And another one problem.. Can you tell me how to open config file in a note pad?

Comment: @user3230466: Open notepad.exe and drag the file into it?  Or select `File->Open` from within notepad?

Comment: @user3230466: Oh, something like this might work then: `Process.Start("notepad.exe", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);`

Comment: @user3230466 Err wait, are you wanting to clone notepad?